# Valid SQL without JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I came across the following `SQL` statement and I was wondering if it was valid:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        registration_waitinglist, 
        registration_registrationprofile 
    WHERE 
        registration_registrationprofile.activation_key = "ALREADY_ACTIVATED"
```

What does the two tables separated by a comma mean?

Comment: This is known as an *implicit join*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `SELECT` data from multiple tables you obtain the `Cartesian Product` of all the tuples from these tables. It can be illustrated in the following way:

[image: Cartesian product illustration]

This means you get each row from the first table paired with all the rows from the second table. Most of the time, it is not what you want. If you really want it, then it's clearer to use the `CROSS JOIN` notation:

```
SELECT * FROM A CROSS JOIN B;
```

Comment: Nice picture :) However, note "the [Cartesian product] analogy is a little loose, because in the Cartesian product the paired elements remain as a pair, whereas JOIN combines them to form a single tuple" -- Hugh Darwen, An Introduction to Relational Database Theory.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it means that you are going to be joining every row from registration_waitinglist to every row in registration_registrationprofile

It's called a cartesian join

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to write the above statement more explicitly/verbosely?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to actually do.  If you WANT to join every row from one table to every row from another table, this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Explicitly this would be: SELECT ... FROM registration_waitinglist CROSS JOIN registration_registrationprofile ..

Comment: @PepperBob - I lean something new every day.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That query is 'syntactically' correct, meaning it will run.  What the query will return is the entire product of every row in registration_waitinglist x registration_registrationprofile.
For example, if there were 2 rows in waitinglist and 3 rows in profile, then 6 rows will be returned.

From a practical matter, this is almost always a logical error and not intended.  With rare exception, there should be either join criteria or criteria in the where clause.